# Can't use google custom font via expo in other part of app

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm loading a google custom font with expo in my `App.js` file as such:

```js
;

import {
  useFonts,
  Poppins_300Light,
  Poppins_400Regular,
  Poppins_400Regular_Italic
} from "@expo-google-fonts/poppins";

export default function App() {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    "Poppins-Light": Poppins_300Light,
    "Poppins-Regular": Poppins_400Regular,
    "Poppins-Regular-Italic": Poppins_400Regular_Italic,
    
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      // Check if user is logged in
      const token = await getKey("access_token");
      if (token) {
        setAuth(true);
      }
    })();
    setLoading(false);
  }, []);

  if (loading || !fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  }

  

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Camera"
       
      >
        {!auth ? (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Analytics"
              component={Analytics}
             
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Settings"
              component={Settings}

            />
           
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Login"
              component={Login}

            />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Now, when I try to use `font-family: Poppins-Light` in my `Login.js` file, I get the error `Unrecognized font family "Poppins-Light"`

Not sure what's going on. I think there may be something wrong with the way I'm loading, and, further, how I am importing the fonts into my `Login` file.

I'm also using styled components so I'm not sure if that has any effect.

Here is my package JSON

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.1.0",
    "@expo-google-fonts/poppins": "^0.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
    "expo": "~40.0.1",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.0.1",
    "expo-camera": "~9.1.0",
    "expo-constants": "~9.3.3",
    "expo-font": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-haptics": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-jwt": "^1.4.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~9.3.0",
    "expo-sqlite": "~8.5.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^2.5.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-global-props": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.15.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-swipeable-views-native": "^0.13.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1"
  },
```

This is how I'm using it in my `Channels.js` file

```js
 <HeaderTitle style={{ fontFamily: "Poppins-Light" }}>
          Channels
        </HeaderTitle>
```

Here is the error when I try to access the page:

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Your help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take look here, [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@pieamo/using-expo-custom-font). Follow the pattern.

If the problem still occurs then please, give a little more code snippet with file structure then we can pinpoint your problem.

Comment: Just updated the question with more of my code.

Comment: @RogerStaxx, I have loaded all the fonts in App.js just like you did and able use these font from Login.js. ( I didn't load all the fonts in my Login.js additionally )

Comment: 1. take a look at the updated [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@pieamo/using-expo-custom-font)

2. I can't see screen name "Camera", is it exists in you code ?

Comment: Just tried your update and it still doesn't work.  I added my package json to the code. Perhaps there is something wrong there?

Comment: @RogerStaxx do you have metro.config.js file?

Answer (score 0):

You need first install, as all google fonts are available there

expo-google-fonts

As in your case you are using Poppins

So

```
expo install @expo-google-fonts/poppins expo-font
```

You can replace Poppins with your custom fonts

You can get it from
https://directory.vercel.app/ => All Google Fonts Expo Package Name

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import {useFonts, Poppins_500Medium} from '@expo-google-fonts/poppins'

export default () => {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Poppins_500Medium,
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>

        <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Poppins_500Medium' }}>
          Your text goes here
        </Text>

      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

You can refer this from https://github.com/expo/google-fonts